A sequence looking like a truncated Pascal triangle
I am studying a sequence defined by $u(k,n) = u(k-1,n-1) + u(k+1, n-1)$ where $k \geq 0$, and $u(\star, n) = 0$ if $\star$ is negative. This has a flavor of Pascal triangle, truncated on the left (because the $u(\star, n) = 0$ condition kills some terms). Let's start with $u(1,1) = 1$ and all the other on the line $n=1$ being zeros. It therefore looks like
$$
\begin{array}[ccccccccc]
 0 & 1 & & & & & & &  \\
1 &  &1 & & & & & &  \\
& 2  &  &1 & & & & &  \\
2& & 3& &1 & & & &  \\
&5 & &4 & &1 & & & \\
5& &9 & &5 & &1 & & \\
& 14 & & 14 & & 6 & & 1  & \\
14 & & 28  & & 20  & & 7  & & 1
\end{array}
$$
i.e. we always sum the two numbers above.
Is this a known sequence, or is there a closed form to it?

Yes and yes: https://oeis.org/A008313 . Found by searching OEIS for the sequence $2,1,2,3,1,5,4,1$ (ie reading the rows of the triangle; I started below the top in case of any issues with defining where the sequence starts, but it seems that wasn't necessary here).

The sum of the entries of row $n$ seems to be $\binom{n}{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor}$, and the leftmost entries appear to be Catalan numbers.

This can be understood nicely in terms of lattice paths in the plane $\mathbb{Z}^2$.
Your $u\left(k,n\right)$ is the number of paths from $\left(0,0\right)$ to $\left(k,n\right)$ that consist of steps $\left(i,j\right) \mapsto \left(i+1,j+1\right)$ and $\left(i,j\right) \mapsto \left(i-1,j+1\right)$ and never move left of the y-axis. (Indeed, your recursion is precisely what you get if you count such paths according to their last step.)
Reflecting the whole picture across the $x=y$ line (i.e., switching the two coordinates of each point), it follows that your $u\left(k,n\right)$ is the number of paths from $\left(0,0\right)$ to $\left(n,k\right)$ that consist of steps $\left(i,j\right) \mapsto \left(i+1,j+1\right)$ and $\left(i,j\right) \mapsto \left(i+1,j-1\right)$ and never move below the x-axis. Such paths are called "Dyck paths", and they can be counted explicitly -- see, e.g., §5.6 in my Math 222 Fall 2022 notes, lecture 29. These paths are in bijection with the "usual" lattice paths (consisting of steps $\left(i,j\right) \mapsto \left(i+1,j\right)$ and $\left(i,j\right) \mapsto \left(i,j+1\right)$) from $\left(0,0\right)$ to $\left(\dfrac{n+k}{2}, \dfrac{n-k}{2}\right)$ that never rise beyond the $x=y$ line (in particular, there are no such paths if $n \not\equiv k \mod 2$ or $k < 0$). (The bijection simply sends each point $\left(a,b\right)$ to $\left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}, \dfrac{a-b}{2}\right)$. Geometrically, it is a spiral homothety around the origin with angle 45°.) The latter paths are known as "Catalan paths" and are counted in Definition 5.2.3 and Theorem 5.2.4 loc. cit.. In particular, this all yields
\begin{align}
u\left(k,n\right)
&= \left(\text{number of Dyck paths from $\left(0,0\right)$ to $\left(n,k\right)$}\right) \\
&= \left(\text{number of Catalan paths from $\left(0,0\right)$ to $\left(\dfrac{n+k}{2}, \dfrac{n-k}{2}\right)$}\right) \\
&= L_{\left(n+k\right)/2, \ \left(n-k\right)/2} \qquad \left(\text{using the notations of Definition 5.2.3 loc. cit.}\right) \\
&= \dbinom{n}{\left(n-k\right)/2} - \dbinom{n}{\left(n-k\right)/2-1} \qquad \left(\text{by Theorem 5.2.4 (c) loc. cit.}\right) \\
&= \dfrac{n-1}{\left(n-k\right)/2+1} \dbinom{n}{\left(n-k\right)/2} \qquad \left(\text{by Theorem 5.2.4 (d) loc. cit.}\right)
\end{align}
whenever $n\geq 0$ and $k\geq 0$.
